# iPhone app pricing model question?

Tags: iphone

I have heard there has been some studies of the apple app store for the iphone.  It was a comparison between having a free application supported by ad vs a .99 cent application. .99 cents seems to be the sweet spot for a lot of the smaller applications. Anyone know where those studies were done? Are people having better success with .99 cents or the free ad supported applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://blog.jwegener.com/2009/02/19/iphone-app-economics-free-vs-paid/) link:

> The Pinch Media numbers show that free
>   apps, as a category, tend to be used
>   6.6 times more often than paid apps (this figure incorporates both the
>   increased download popularity of free
>   apps and also the slightly decreased
>   frequency-of-use of free apps versus
>   paid apps).  On average, free
>   applications are used heavily at first
>   but usage levels off quickly — the
>   average app lifetime is 12 runs.
>
> So compared to a single paid app,
>   making an app free results in 6.6x
>   more app uses and at an average
>   lifetime of 12 runs/app = 80 sessions.
>   Remember that the paid app makes 70c. 
>   So the question becomes “Can the
>   average free application make up 70c
>   in advertising revenue across 80 usage
>   sessions?”
>
> Greg’s answer: “Hell No.” Assuming one
>   ad is shown per each session, this
>   requires a CPM of $8.75. 
>   Unfortunately, typical CPMs are 50c –
>   $2.00, far below the point required to
>   match the paid app’s revenue.  Unless
>   your app can serve 18 ads per session
>   (assuming a worst case 50c CPM), or
>   there’s some especially ’sticky’
>   property that makes users reliably use
>   your app repeatedly, Greg concludes
>   that charging for your app is
>   generally a good idea.

See link above for slides and additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I personally hate when apps have ads in them.

I'd be more willing to pay a dollar than to deal with an ad every time I use it.

Comment: Apparently the people in the link quoted above agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) has the answer:  [Software Pricing: Are We Doing It Wrong?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001293.html)